# Oracle Database connectionstring?

Tags: database, oracle

Can any one give the connectionstring sample to connect Oracle database with Visual Studio 2012.

I have written as follows. Is it the right ??

```
 <connectionStrings>
<add name="EmployeeContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=Oracle.DataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;data source=XE;password=oracle;user id=ITCORE&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Visual Studio, but this might be of your interest:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xexk8kx3%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Also If you need a JDBC driver, you can download it here:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/jdbc/index-091264.html

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

These pages provide many samples, you should find one.

http://www.carlprothman.net/Default.aspx?tabid=81

http://www.connectionstrings.com/